# aggregate queries optimisation

Tags: mysql

I need to aggregate all sales by days to build graph.

I have such a table

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expires_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expires_date_calculated` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payment_account_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `payment_account_id` (`payment_account_id`),
  KEY `expires_date` (`expires_date`)
);
```

with the following data

```
INSERT INTO transaction
 (product_id, purchase_date, expires_date, expires_date_calculated, payment_account_id) 
VALUES 
 ('a', 1164357246, 0, 1264357246, 2),
 ('a', 1345117819, 0, 1435413246, 1),
 ('b', 1345117907, 0, 1440683646, 2),
 ('c', 1345119400, 1464357246, 0, 5),
 ('b', 1345119625, 0, 1464357246, 10),
 ('a', 1345120085, 0, 1464357246, 2),
 ('b', 1345121092, 0, 1464357246, 5),
 ('a', 1464357246, 0, 1564357246, 2) ;
```

And I have a function which triggers the following query 32 times with different date values

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT payment_account_id) AS cnt
FROM transaction
WHERE (purchase_date < 1345120085  
       AND (expires_date > 1345120085 OR expires_date_calculated > 1345120085))
  AND (
    `product_id` IN
    (
      'a',
      'b'
    )
  );
```

And it works very slow. I want to replace it by one big query with 32 SUM(IF())

```
SELECT
  sum(IF((purchase_date < 1345120085 
          AND (expires_date > 1345120085 OR expires_date_calculated > 1345120085)), 
        1, 0)) AS day1
#...
FROM (
       SELECT
         payment_account_id,
         (purchase_date)           AS purchase_date,
         (expires_date)            AS expires_date,
         (expires_date_calculated) AS expires_date_calculated
       FROM transaction
       WHERE
         `product_id` IN
         (
           'a',
           'b'
         )
         AND payment_account_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY payment_account_id
     ) AS tmp;
```

[SQL Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7994d/1)

But I get wrong result. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect the second query to be faster? Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) on the original query and add the results to the question together with results of `show create table transaction;`.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data and expected output, plus an explanation of what the "wrong result" is in the second query?

Comment: The 2nd query is obviously ill-writen. It uses `GROUP BY payment_account_id` but the `SELECT` list contains other non-aggregated columns.

Comment: out of curiosity, what kind of date is 1442880000 ?  Seconds since 1970?

Comment: @jkavalik because the second query is called just once with 32 IF(). The first one is called 32 times.

Comment: @MaxVernon Yep. It's a timestamp

Comment: @Tux-oid Thats hidden in the `#...`? I did not understand that. You might be able to design a group by clause to count it in one run by the first query. Or we can help you make it faster if you give us enough information.

Comment: @jkavalik there is a 32 similar IFs with different dates hidden under the #...

Comment: Tux-oid I see now, But what @ypercube wrote still stands. Can you maybe prepare an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data? And add more info to the question.

Comment: @jkavalik  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50890/1

Comment: Moderators a fixed the question description. Please remove it from hold

Comment: @Tux-oid please add the info about what changes between the 32 queries/sums, only the timestamps? In the meantime check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30d98/1 - I added one index to make the "first" query fast.

Comment: @jkavalik yep. Only timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the solution.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(day1 >0, 1, 0))
  #...
  FROM(
      SELECT
      payment_account_id, sum(day1) AS day1
      #...
        FROM (
           SELECT
             payment_account_id,
             IF((purchase_date < 1345120085 AND (expires_date > 1345120085 OR expires_date_calculated > 1345120085)), 1, 0) AS day1
            #...
           FROM transaction
           WHERE
             `product_id` IN
             (
               'a',
               'b'
             )
             AND payment_account_id IS NOT NULL
          ) AS tmp
      GROUP BY payment_account_id
     )
     AS tmp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your original query for more than one conditions, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN purchase_date < 1345120085  
                            AND ( expires_date > 1345120085 
                               OR expires_date_calculated > 1345120085) 
                        THEN payment_account_id
                      END
            ) AS cnt1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN <condition 2>
                        THEN payment_account_id
                      END
            ) AS cnt2,
       -- etc.
FROM `transaction`
WHERE product_id IN ('a', 'b') ;
```

---

Your solution seems correct, too. It can be simplified to remove the two nested derived tables to one:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(day1 > 0) AS cnt1,
    SUM(day2 > 0) AS cnt2,
    -- etc,
FROM
  ( SELECT
        payment_account_id, 
        SUM( purchase_date < 1345120085 
             AND ( expires_date > 1345120085 
                OR expires_date_calculated > 1345120085)
           ) AS day1,
        SUM( <condition 2> ) AS day2,
        --- etc, 
    FROM `transaction`
    WHERE product_id IN ('a', 'b')
      AND payment_account_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY payment_account_id
  ) AS tmp ;
```

Comment: `INDEX(product_id)` may help.